# Press home button to stop service

Tags: java, android

i want to if the user press home button my service will be stop , this is my code but it's not working for me, please help me:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to make sure the service only runs when the related activity is visible, a better solution would be to stop the service in the onPause() method of whatever activity the user is running.  That way, the event is handled when the user presses "back" and when the user presses "home".

Likewise, you can bind your service to the activity (or activities).  The bound service will be destroyed when all activities bound to it stop.

Comment: In that case maybe a service isn't even necessary... using AsyncTask might be enough.

Comment: A service wouldn't be necessary for this specific case (from what I gather).  A timer, asynctask, or generic thread would probably suffice.  However, if the service is already implemented (perhaps from another application or will be used as a service in another application), then this is a good solution.  Also, to answer the question "Can I access and override the home button?": The answer is "no" from what I gather.  It's solely meant to force exit a program, so overriding it could be dangerous.

Comment: I've also using onPause() method.

Answer (score 3):

> public static final int KEYCODE_HOME
>
> This key is handled by the
>   framework and is **never delivered to applications**.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME)

Comment: Users do not interact with services directly. You may use a Notification instead but its highly dependent on your what your application does.

Comment: I assume he's just trying to make sure the service stops when his activity is not visible.  In which case, using the home key is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a root activity and add this,

```
@Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);
        if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
            // Get called every-time when application went to background.
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
```

extend each activity with rootActivity, it will shutdown service on home/menu button press